# data not getting displayed/plotted in highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have controller written in c# which will written data in json format .....

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="graphs.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutomationWebPortal.graphs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 100
                },
                series: []
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: './graphs.aspx/GetDataForTotalPassedFailTime',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    options.series[0].data = data;
                    alert(options.series[0].data);
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/libs/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

JSON format response : =

```
[
    624.3519791, 
    162.30429669999998, 
    170.67211089999998, 
    352.8677317, 
    0.0, 
    0.0, 
    97.306944899999991, 
    0.0, 
    305.1448274, 
    2514.6032158999997, 
    2225.8082492999997, 
    2415.6067002, 
    568.1111355999999, 
    2510.9615231000002
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON data into an array than pass it to `series: []` parameter of highchart in order to form your graph.

Have a look on it, it might help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: './graphs.aspx/GetDataForTotalPassedFailTime',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (dataR) {
                    alert(dataR);

                    var options = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            type: 'spline'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            align: 'right',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            x: 0,
                            y: 100
                        },
                        series: [{data:dataR}]
                    };
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hi chandan, I have returned array of json if I hard-code JSON, Highchart works but after your suggested changes also not working ..... really not able to get cause.

Comment: Hi Sushil, I am sure it is problem w.r.t. to JSON data format. What you do for debugging it is mannually create expected JSON array object and pass it to "series" parameter. Than you can figure out where your data format is going wrong

Comment: I created JSFiddle using your code, please look it once: https://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/mL4y8pam/1/

Comment: Sorry I sent private link mistakenly. Try this fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/chandansharma/kveu8mfu/

Comment: Hi chandan, but I am returning array in JSON format like [1,2,3,4]. You are right there is problem with JSON array.

Comment: One suggestion do one thing, create an Array in Javascript. Put all your data coming from JSON array to javascript array object. than pass that object to your graph. (and for confirmation print that js array in alert, to make sure object format is correct)

Comment: I found cause Chandan array is coming like "[1,2,3,4]" which is invalid it shoudl be [1,2,3,4]. I have passed array obj to highchart then work. Now I need to convert my JSON string into array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please call your two scripts in your head section and before your `$(document).ready();` function

`<script src="js/libs/highcharts.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/libs/exporting.js"></script>`